# how to connect to rtsp camera from docker container?

Tags: python, docker, opencv, rtsp

I'm trying to get stream from IP camera with the help of openCV. Non-docker app runs fine on my PC, but i need to run it in a docker container. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM jjanzic/docker-python3-opencv
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["./CameraMan.py"]
```

```
src = 'rtsp://admin:....'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.src)
cap.isOpened()
```

When i run the container, the last line always returns false. What am i missing?

Comment: If it helps to eliminate doubt that it can be possible: I just tested your exact code on my machine and it works just fine. Docker shouldn't be blocking any kind of traffic going out, so it's expected that it should work first time. On what OS are you?

Comment: @VictorSonck I'm using centos 8

Comment: I would assume that this is a docker issue rather than a OpenCV issue. I am not sure what ports are involved with RTSP but you need to make sure that these ports are mapped correctly between the container and the host.

Comment: I`m having the same issue, the RTSP port is 514 by default. But even with settings docker --net host I can`t connect to my camera. Did you perhaps already found a solution?

Comment: @semenchukou to be on the same page IP camera is in local network (WiFi network on your own router), right?

Comment: I faced the same issue on macOS, and turning firewall ON fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the ip in "rtsp://user:pass@ip:port/.." to 0.0.0.0. So in you python script set:

> src = "rtsp://user:pass@0.0.0.0:554/..."

and you need to map your host rtsp host port '554' to the container port '554'. So call you container as follow:

> docker run -p 554:554 *youDockerName*

Hope this solves the problem!